# Python: How to join table by time condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have an original data called df1. I would like to join df2 to df1 with the following **conditions**:
1) Match `CaseNo` col of df2 to df1.
2) For each `CaseNo`, the `Request Date` col of df2 must fall between the Movement_Start_Date of the current row and proceeding/following row.
3) If there is > 1 `RequestDate` that satisfies condition 2, we choose the latest date (max 1 `RequestDate` per `Movement_Sequence_No`).

How do I go about this in Python?
df1:
[image]
df2:
[image]
Expected Output:
[image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'Movement_Sequence_No':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    'Movement_Start_Date':['2020-02-09 22:17:00','2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19',
                                           '2020-02-18 11:22:52','2020-02-12 23:00:00','2020-02-24 10:26:35',
                                           '2020-03-03 17:50:00','2020-03-17 08:24:19'],
                    'Movement_End_Date':['2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19','2020-02-18 11:22:52',
                                         '2020-02-25 13:55:37','2020-02-24 10:26:35','2020-03-03 17:50:00',
                                         '9999-12-31 23:59:59','2020-03-18 18:50:00'],
                    'Category':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                    'RequestDate':['2020-02-16 13:04:20','2020-02-17 09:10:10','2020-02-18 07:11:11',
                                   '2020-02-20 14:03:55','2020-02-21 21:30:30','2020-02-27 12:52:10',
                                   '2020-02-13 22:00:00','2020-03-15 09:40:00','2020-03-17 09:45:20',
                                  '2020-03-18 09:26:19','2020-03-18 15:10:10'],
                    'Platelets':['189','207','190','195','188','241','328','266','180','210','310']})
```

Comment: i have edited the first row issue, it was a typo. Row index 6 with a Movement_End_Date in 9999 is correct - it is a placeholder for the movement not being ended yet. u can think of it as `movement_sequence_no` 4 being part of `movement_sequence_no` 3, if it helps to reconcile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `merge_asof`. First convert your columns to datetime, then `merge_asof` `sort_values` and keep the rows that meet your conditions with `query` and `drop_duplicates`. Finally `merge` back to `df1` to get the rows that did not match with the `merge_asof`.

```
df1['Movement_Start_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['Movement_Start_Date'])
df1['Movement_End_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['Movement_End_Date'], errors='coerce')\
                              .fillna(pd.Timestamp.now()).dt.floor('s')
df2['RequestDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['RequestDate'])

df_f = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('RequestDate'), 
                      df1.sort_values('Movement_Start_Date'), 
                      by=['CaseNo'], 
                      left_on=['RequestDate'], right_on=['Movement_Start_Date'], 
                      direction='backward')
          .sort_values(['CaseNo', 'Movement_Sequence_No'])
          .query('RequestDate <= Movement_End_Date')
          .drop_duplicates(['CaseNo', 'Movement_Sequence_No'], keep='last')
         )
df_f = df1.merge(df_f, how='outer')
```

and you get

```
print (df_f)
   CaseNo  Movement_Sequence_No Movement_Start_Date   Movement_End_Date  \
0       1                     1 2020-02-09 22:17:00 2020-02-10 17:19:41   
1       1                     2 2020-02-10 17:19:41 2020-02-17 08:04:19   
2       1                     3 2020-02-17 08:04:19 2020-02-18 11:22:52   
3       1                     4 2020-02-18 11:22:52 2020-02-25 13:55:37   
4       2                     1 2020-02-12 23:00:00 2020-02-24 10:26:35   
5       2                     2 2020-02-24 10:26:35 2020-03-03 17:50:00   
6       2                     3 2020-03-03 17:50:00 2020-05-21 12:44:11   
7       2                     4 2020-03-17 08:24:19 2020-03-18 18:50:00   

  Category         RequestDate Platelets  
0        A                 NaT       NaN  
1        A 2020-02-16 13:04:20       189  
2        A 2020-02-18 07:11:11       190  
3        A 2020-02-21 21:30:30       188  
4        B 2020-02-13 22:00:00       328  
5        B                 NaT       NaN  
6        B 2020-03-15 09:40:00       266  
7        B 2020-03-18 15:10:10       310
```

Comment: amazing..first time learning of merge_asof function. let me digest it b4 accepting ans. thx

Comment: u are brilliant!